# Create Runtime LinkButton

Tags: c#

For creating runtime linkbutton i used this code

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            r = new TableRow();
        t.Rows.Add(r);

        for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
        {
            c = new TableCell();

            r.Cells.Add(c);

            LinkButton btnLnk = new LinkButton();
            btnLnk.Text = "Hello";
            btnLnk.Visible = true;
            btnLnk.CommandName = "Test";
            btnLnk.CommandArgument = "1";
            btnLnk.ID = "Hi";

            c.Controls.Add(ll);

        }

    }
```

This Error is occured...

"Control 'ctl34' of type 'LinkButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server. "

Please give me soluation for this

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you table (t) is inside the form tag.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the Form in which this table is located to which you are adding a LinkButton does not specify the runat=server attribute, or this Table is not in the Form at all.

Make sure you have something like this.

```
<form runat="server">
 <!--table to which you are adding your rows-->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

first give id to your form say `<form id="myForm" runat="server">`

then in code behind you can add table to the form like this

```
myForm.Controls.Add(t);
```